# How to get a value where button click?

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my code. I am trying to make a quiz game but I limit the form 10 where button click = 10 I show the value student

This my code to show the question

```
public void perintahsql()
{
    sql = "SELECT * FROM soal ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    tsoal = koneksi.tampil_data(sql);
    ide = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    soale = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    ae = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
    be = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
    ce = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString();
    de = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
    je = tsoal.Rows[0].ItemArray[6].ToString();
    textBox1.Text = soale;

    label1.Text = ide;
    rbA.Text = ae;
    rbB.Text = be;
    rbC.Text = ce;
    rbD.Text = de;
    //total();

    labeljawabanpersoal.Text = je;  //ini sebelumnya ga ada (yg jadi masalah nya)
    //int total=0;      //ga kepake bisa dihapus
    string rb = "";
    //labeljawabanpersoal.Visible= false;  //ini pindahin ke load aja

    if (rbA.Checked)
    {        
        //=true nya dihapus atau seharusnya ganti jadi == true (double samadengan)
        rb = "A";
    }
    else if (rbB.Checked)
    {
        rb = "B";
    }
    else if (rbC.Checked)
    {
        rb = "C";
    }
    else if (rbD.Checked)
    {
        rb = "D";
    }

    if (rb == labeljawabanpersoal.Text)
    {
        labelskor.Text = Convert.ToString(Int32.Parse(labelskor.Text) + 10);
    }
}
```

when button click i try this code

```
private void buttonnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    i = 10;
    if (1 != 0)
    {
        perintahsql();
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        bukanilai();
    }  

    }

public void bukanilai()
{
    Nilai N = new Nilai();
    N.ShowDialog();
}
```

why when i click 10 times i cant show new form

Comment: `if (1 != 0)` should be `if (i != 0)` and also their is no chance for `else` since `i` will always be `10` declare `i` outside this handler

Comment: first, you need to declare `i` variable as a global variable. Then in button next, it would be `if (i < 10)`

Comment: Follow @Mark, Finally, you should reset i = 0; after call bukanilai(); method.

Comment: i changes 1 to I and i = 0;
but its dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `i` must be a global variable
2. `i = 10;` must be removed in click event
3. `if (1 != 0)` must be changed to `if (i < 10)`
4. Should set `i = 0;` after called `bukanilai();`

> ```
> private int i = 0;    
> private void buttonnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   // int i; (old) => Must move to global variable
>   // i = 10; (old)
>   if (i < 10) // if (1 != 0) (old)
>   {
>       perintahsql();
>       i++;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       bukanilai();
>       i = 0; // Maybe add this line
>   }    
> }
> ```